# magento: add custom html on every page

Tags: javascript, magento

I'd like to add some simple html code that makes use of javascript and .css, on every page of my website (magento).

I have figured out where to add the javascript and .css files in the head section.

Want to know where to put the html code? (possibly within the `<body></body>` tags, not in the `<head></head>`section)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a configuration field in the backend for statistics, tracker, etc.

```
System > Configuration > Design > Footer
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. No, It's not a tracker code. It is the code to get a jquery popup for the purpose of age verification.

Comment: but you don'T want it on every page, do you? If not, you should use the correct layout handle. and add it only to the pages, where it is needed

Comment: well i have added the code to footer, but can't get the splashbox working. Do u think there's an issue with jquery?
should i only use javascript?

Comment: Magento uses prototype, so to use jQuery you have to call jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: The thing is, I want to add age verification box like [this one](http://www.johnsoncreeksmokejuice.com/). Could you help me out?  Don't know where to start.